# How to show battery status in figures in 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery

I have just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.1 LTS.In 16.04 I could see the battery icon on the screen with time till flat and percentage charge showing as hours/minutes and a percentage in the top bar. This doesn't seem to be available as an easily configurable permanent display option in 18.04.

Can anyone please tell me how I can make it display this?